# Angular - How can I set the video src from navigator.getUserMedia?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to set up a webcam stream for a video element in Angular.

```
    import {Component, View, bootstrap} from "angular2/angular2";

    @Component({
        selector: "home",
    })
    @View({
        template:`<video [src]="videosrc"></video>`
    })
    export default class Home {

        videosrc: string;
        constructor(){

            //setTimeout(() => {}, 2000);

            navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
            navigator.getUserMedia({video: true},(stream) => {
                this.videosrc= URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            }, (err) => console.log(err));  
        }
    }
```

Its working only after adding the line "setTimeout(() => {}, 2000);".

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/h4fN7l5qmO4SzHU5VTB1)

Comment: What should we see? I see the plnkr failing with a `NavigatorUserMediaError` and a black screen, but the timeout doesn't seem to solve anything

Comment: You are right I didnt explain, it should use 'navigator.getUserMedia' and and get video stream from a webcam. So you must have a webcam attached to test it.

Answer (score 0):

you must bind [srcObject]  to media stream

```
<video id="device" [srcObject]="localSource" controls autoplay></video>

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })
  .then(stream => this.localSource=stream);
```

Answer (score -1):

Changes detection needs to be triggered once you set the src url. 
Wrapping the getUserMedia call into a Promise will solve your issue. You should also be able to call Lifecycle.tick() manually.

```
var promise= new Promise<string>((resolve, reject)=>{
          navigator.getUserMedia({video: true},(stream) => {
            resolve(stream);
          }, (err) => reject(err));  
        }).then((stream)=>{
            this.videosrc= URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        }).catch((error)=>{
          console.log(error);
        });
```

See the updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/G9Y4Rk17pNP5XwHzDNko?p=preview